# Accordion Style Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I wanted to make a navigation bar with an accordion style, just like this:

http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/

If you click an item, say "Categories", there appears the accordion. I want to implement this kind of navigation bar as well but as I inspected the element, it mainly uses a table instead of `<ul>` and I still have no idea how to do it plus it I think it also uses jQuery or javascript of some sort which I'm also a newbie with.

I tried copying the menu structure in http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/, so here:

```
<ul>
   <table width="100%">
      <tbody width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="220px;"><font style="letter-spacing:3px; padding-left:50px; font-size:13px;padding-right:20px; font-weight:600; color:#000000;"><a href="http://www.ordinarypeople.ca" style="color:#fff; font-weight:600; font-size:13px;">ORDINARY PEOPLE</a></font></td>
            <td valign="top" width="90px">
               <section class="ac-container">
                  <div>
                     <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox">
                     <label for="ac-1">ABOUT</label>
                     <article class="ac-small">
                        <div style="padding-left:200px; padding-top:30px;padding-right:200px;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;">
                           <center>Alyssa Lau is the 23-year-old face and voice behind the Edmonton-based style blog, Ordinary People. A creative director, public relations coordinator, content developer, photographer, and entrepreneur, Alyssa is currently involved with various fashion-related projects after deciding against a postgraduate degree in Biochemistry. Since then, Alyssa has launched a women's sustainable and fair trade fashion e-commerce store that goes by the name of <u><a href="http://www.newclassics.ca" style="letter-spacing:1px; text-transform:Capitalize;padding:0px;color:#222;font-size:12px;" target="_blank">New Classics Studios</a></u>, which is proudly based in Edmonton. <br><br><a href="http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/2014/12/personal-blah-blah-blah-g.html" target="_blank"><b>READ MORE</b></a><br><br><a href="http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/p/ask-alyssa.html"><b>ASK ME QUESTIONS</b></a></center>
                        </div>
                     </article>
                  </div>
               </section>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="90px">
               <section class="ac-container">
                  <div>
                     <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-2" type="checkbox">
                     <label for="ac-2">CONTACT</label>
                     <article class="ac-medium">
                        <div style="padding-left:200px; padding-top:30px;padding-right:200px;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;">
                           <center>
                              GENERAL ENQUIRIES<br>
                              <font style="font-size:10px;"><a href="mailto:alyssa@ordinarypeople.ca" style="letter-spacing:1px; text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;color:#555;font-size:10px;">ALYSSA@ORDINARYPEOPLE.CA</a></font>
                              <br><br>
                              COMMERCIAL PROJECTS<br>
                              <font style="font-size:10px;"><a href="mailto:eric@ordinarypeople.ca" style="letter-spacing:1px; text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;color:#555;font-size:10px;">ERIC@ORDINARYPEOPLE.CA</a></font>
                           </center>
                        </div>
                     </article>
                  </div>
               </section>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="90px">
               <section class="ac-container">
                  <div>
                     <input id="ac-3" name="accordion-3" type="checkbox">
                     <label for="ac-3">SOCIAL</label>
                     <article class="ac-large">
                        <div style="padding-left:200px;z-index:90; padding-top:30px;padding-right:200px;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;">
                           <center>
                              <div style="align:center">
                                 <ul id="fnav">
                                    <li><a class="ex1" href="https://twitter.com/imalyssalau" style="letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;color:#fff;" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.songofstyle.com/wp-content/themes/ponsonby/image/twtr.png" style="-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-3px;" width="15px"> Twitter</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="ex2" href="http://facebook.com/ordinarypeople" style="letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.songofstyle.com/wp-content/themes/ponsonby/image/fb.png" style="-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-3px;" width="15px"> Facebook </a></li>
                                    <li><a class="ex7" href="http://youtube.com/ordinarypeoplevid" style="letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/r6gh7XZ.png" style="-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-8px;" width="27px">YouTube </a></li>
                                    <li><a class="ex4" href="http://instagram.com/imalyssalau" style="letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;" target="_blank">
                                       <img src="http://www.songofstyle.com/wp-content/themes/ponsonby/image/insta.png" style="-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-3px;" width="15px"> Instagram </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a class="ex6" href="http://pinterest.com/imalyssalau" style="letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.songofstyle.com/wp-content/themes/ponsonby/image/pntrst.png" style="-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-3px;" width="15px">Pinterest </a></li>
                                    <li><a class="ex3" href="https://www.bloglovin.com/blogs/ordinary-people-2697392" style="letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.songofstyle.com/wp-content/themes/ponsonby/image/blog.png" style="-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-3px;" width="15px"> Bloglovin' </a></li>
                                 </ul>
                              </div>
                           </center>
                        </div>
                     </article>
                  </div>
               </section>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="90px"><a href="http://www.newclassics.ca" style="font-weight:600; font-family: arial; letter-spacing;3px; font-size:11px; ;color:#666; align:center;" target="_blank">SHOP</a></td>
            <td valign="top" width="90px">
               <section class="ac-container">
                  <div>
                     <input id="ac-4" name="accordion-4" type="checkbox">
                     <label for="ac-4">CATEGORIES</label>
                     <article class="ac-categories">
                        <div style="padding-left:200px; padding-top:30px;padding-right:200px;font-size:11px;letter-spacing:1px;">
                           <center><a href="http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Outfits?max-results=9">WEARING</a><br><br>
                              <a href="http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Travel?max-results=9">TRAVEL</a><br><br>
                              <a href="http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Photoshoot?max-results=9">PHOTOSHOOTS</a><br><br>
                              <a href="http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Tutorial?max-results=9">TUTORIALS</a><br><br>
                              <a href="http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Video?max-results=9">VIDEO</a><br><br>
                              <a href="http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Beauty?max-results=9">HAIR AND BEAUTY</a><br><br>
                           </center>
                        </div>
                     </article>
                  </div>
               </section>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="150px">
               <form action="/search" id="searchThis" method="get" style="display: inline; "><input id="searchBox" name="q" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" style="border: 1px solid #bbbbbb; background: none;" type="text" value="" vinput="">
                  <input id="searchButton" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
               </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <li><a href="#">_</a></li>
</ul>
```

As what I've said, I still have no idea about the jQuery/javascript behind all this.

I am using this for a blog (Blogger), fyi.
Hoping anybody can help.

Comment: show us what you tried until now

Comment: It uses jQuery, you need to create a div with the menu in, hide it with css and use jQuery's animate function to show it on click... at least that is one way of doing it...

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon I just edited my question. Lupy, how exactly? sorry I'm not proficient in jQuery.

Comment: the HTML is invalid anyway. Only `li` are permitted as children of a `ul` and it looks like it is using tables for layout which isn't really recommended as best practice any more. It use break tags for spacing (sigh) and the `font` element has been deprecated. I'd use someone else's code for a better example. Not the best code to use as a starting point.

Comment: @Paulie_D oh I see so how can I make an accordion with `<ul>`? and that site's accordion is working fine tho.

Comment: @kaynewilder That's a **very** broad question and so off-topic for SO although a search with Google should find you many examples. The fact that someone's code "works" doesn't make it valid or good.

Comment: @Paulie_D I did searching with Google before I posted this question here. guess I didn't find any answer, all I searched were mostly vertical accordion menus. And yes I understand your point.

Comment: @kaynewilder why not start learning basic jQuery and come back to it? Its not very hard and its going to be totally worth it if you want to construct something like that...

Comment: @Lupy yes I thought so too, and that's really a great idea. but I'm running out of time. sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember where I adapted the code for this from, but I'll attach what I'm using right now :)

Hope it helps!

Alyssa (www.ordinarypeople.ca)

```css
.ac-container{

 margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
.ac-container label{
 font-family: arial;
 padding: 0px 0px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 20;
 width: 90px;
letter-spacing:3px;
text-align:center;
text-transform: uppercase;
 display: block;
 height: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
font-weight:600;
 color: #000;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
 line-height: auto;
 font-size: 11px;
 background: linear-gradient(top, #d4cfcf 100%,#d4cfcf 100%);
 box-shadow: 
  0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
  0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9) inset, 
  0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.ac-container label:hover{
 background: #d4cfcf;
}
.ac-container input:checked + label,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover{
 background: #d4cfcf;
 color: #f9f9f9;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
 box-shadow: 
  0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
  0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.ac-container label:hover:after,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 right: 13px;
 top: 7px;
 background: transparent url(../images/arrow_down.png) no-repeat center center; 
}
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
 background-image: url(../images/arrow_up.png);
}
.ac-container input{
 display: none;
}
.ac-container article{
 background: #d4cfcf repeat;
 margin-top: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
width:100%;
left:0px;
 height: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 transition: 
  height 0.3s ease-in-out, 
  box-shadow 0.6s linear;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article{
 transition: 
  height 0.5s ease-in-out, 
  box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(155,155,155,0.3);
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small{
 height: 165px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-medium{
 height: 130px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-large{
 height: 90px;}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-categories{
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table width='100%'><tbody width='100%'><tr>
<td valign='top' width='220px'><font style='letter-spacing:3px; font-size:13px;padding-right:20px; font-weight:600; color:#000000'><a href='http://www.ordinarypeople.ca' style='color:#fff; font-weight:600; font-size:13px; '><div style='width:220px; overflow:hidden; padding-left:50px;margin-top:-15px;'>ORDINARY PEOPLE</div></a></font></td>





<td valign='top' width='110px'>

<section class='ac-container'>
 <div>
  <input id='ac-1' name='accordion-1' type='checkbox'/>
  <label for='ac-1'>ABOUT</label>
  <article class='ac-small'>
   <div style='padding-left:200px; padding-top:30px;padding-right:200px;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;'><center>Alyssa Lau is the 23-year-old face and voice behind the Edmonton-based style blog, Ordinary People. A creative director, public relations coordinator, content developer, photographer, and entrepreneur, Alyssa is currently involved with various fashion-related projects after deciding against a postgraduate degree in Biochemistry. Since then, Alyssa has launched a women&#39;s sustainable and fair trade fashion e-commerce store that goes by the name of <u><a href='http://www.newclassics.ca' style='letter-spacing:1px; text-transform:Capitalize;padding:0px;color:#222;font-size:12px;' target='_blank'>New Classics Studios</a></u>, which is proudly based in Edmonton. <br/><br/><a href='http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/2014/12/personal-blah-blah-blah-g.html' target='_blank'><b>READ MORE</b></a><br/><br/><a href='http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/p/ask-alyssa.html'><b>ASK ME QUESTIONS</b></a></center></div>
  </article>
  </div></section></td>
 <td valign='top' width='110px'><section class='ac-container'><div>
  <input id='ac-2' name='accordion-2' type='checkbox'/>
  <label for='ac-2'>CONTACT</label>
  <article class='ac-medium'>
  <div style='padding-left:200px; padding-top:30px;padding-right:200px;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;'>
          <center>


            GENERAL ENQUIRIES<br/>
            <font style='font-size:10px;'><a href='mailto:alyssa@ordinarypeople.ca' style='letter-spacing:1px; text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;color:#555;font-size:10px;'>ALYSSA@ORDINARYPEOPLE.CA</a></font>
<br/><br/>
COMMERCIAL PROJECTS<br/>
            <font style='font-size:10px;'><a href='mailto:eric@ordinarypeople.ca' style='letter-spacing:1px; text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;color:#555;font-size:10px;'>ERIC@ORDINARYPEOPLE.CA</a></font>

</center>
          </div>
  </article>
 </div>
 
      </section></td>
<td valign='top' width='110px'><section class='ac-container'><div>
  <input id='ac-3' name='accordion-3' type='checkbox'/>
  <label for='ac-3'>SOCIAL</label>
  <article class='ac-large'>
   <div style='padding-left:200px;z-index:90; padding-top:30px;padding-right:200px;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;'>
          <center>
<div style='align:center'>
<ul id='fnav'>
<li><a class='ex1' href='https://twitter.com/imalyssalau' style='letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;color:#fff;' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.songofstyle.com/wp-content/themes/ponsonby/image/twtr.png' style='-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-3px;' width='15px'/> Twitter</a></li>
<li><a class='ex2' href='http://facebook.com/ordinarypeople' style='letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.songofstyle.com/wp-content/themes/ponsonby/image/fb.png' style='-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-3px;' width='15px'/> Facebook </a></li>

<li><a class='ex7' href='http://youtube.com/ordinarypeoplevid' style='letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.imgur.com/r6gh7XZ.png' style='-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-8px;' width='27px'/>YouTube </a></li>

<li><a class='ex4' href='http://instagram.com/imalyssalau' style='letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;' target='_blank'>

<img src='http://www.songofstyle.com/wp-content/themes/ponsonby/image/insta.png' style='-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-3px;' width='15px'/> Instagram </a></li>

<li><a class='ex6' href='http://pinterest.com/imalyssalau' style='letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.songofstyle.com/wp-content/themes/ponsonby/image/pntrst.png' style='-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-3px;' width='15px'/>Pinterest </a></li>
<li><a class='ex3' href='https://www.bloglovin.com/blogs/ordinary-people-2697392' style='letter-spacing:2px; line-height:22px; font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px;font-size:10px;' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.songofstyle.com/wp-content/themes/ponsonby/image/blog.png' style='-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);margin-bottom:-3px;' width='15px'/> Bloglovin&#39; </a></li>
  </ul></div>

           

              </center></div>
  </article>
 </div>
 
      </section></td>
     <td valign='top' width='110px'><a href='http://www.newclassics.ca' style='font-weight:600; font-family: arial; letter-spacing;3px; font-size:11px; ;color:#666; align:center;' target='_blank'>SHOP</a></td>
    
 
<td valign='top' width='110px'>
<div>
<section class='ac-container'>

  <input id='ac-4' name='accordion-4' type='checkbox'/>
  <label for='ac-4'>CATEGORIES</label>
  <article class='ac-categories'>
   <div style='padding-left:200px; padding-top:30px;padding-right:200px;font-size:11px;letter-spacing:1px;'><center><a href='http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Outfits?max-results=6'>WEARING</a><BR/>
              <a href='http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Travel?max-results=6'>TRAVEL</a><BR/>
              <a href='http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Photoshoot?max-results=9'>PHOTOSHOOTS</a><BR/>
              <a href='http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Tutorial?max-results=6'>TUTORIALS</a><BR/>
<a href='http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Personal?max-results=6'>PERSONAL</a><BR/>
              <a href='http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/search/label/Beauty?max-results=6'>HAIR AND BEAUTY</a><br/><br/></center></div>
  </article>
</section>  </div></td>
 






<td valign='top' width='220px'><div class='searchbox' id='searchbox'><form action='/search' id='searchThis' method='get' style='display: inline; '><input id='searchBox' name='q' onblur='if(this.value==&apos;&apos;)this.value=this.defaultValue;' onfocus='if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=&apos;&apos;;' style='border: 1px solid #bbbbbb; background: none;' type='text' value='' vinput=''/> <input id='searchButton' type='submit' value='SEARCH'/></form></div></td>
     </tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

In its simplest form you need to animate the Headers height and append the data bellow it. You will require a higher css `z-index` value for the header to show above all other page content.

I created a simple Demo to give you a start

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/10uavzd4/

**Code**

```
    // click option, animate header to to 120 pixels height, when the animation is done (completed) append Data just below the header.

$(".about").on("click", function () {
    $(".info").empty()
    $("#header").animate({
        height: "120px"
    }, 400).promise().done(function () {
        $("#header").append("<span class='info'>This is some info</span>")
    })
})

$(".contact").on("click", function () {
    $(".info").empty()
    $("#header").animate({
        height: "120px"
    }, 400).promise().done(function () {
        $("#header").append("<span class='info'>Contact Information</span>")
    })

})
```

Comment: thanks! but I noticed when I click back an item, the accordion does not hide back or slide up to where it cannot be seen.

Comment: You can animate it to whatever height you wish, if you mean the original height of the header then its 58 pixels in the demo

Comment: I mean how do I let the appended `<span>` contents slide back up when I click the parent item again. for example, when I click "About", its contents will be shown below/slide down, but when I click "About" again, its contents will slide back up then hidden, just like in http://www.ordinarypeople.ca/

Comment: You need to use a variable for the state of the header if up or down, hold on i do a demo for you

Comment: @kaynewilder here you go a simple demo that checks if the header is up or down and what option fire it -- https://jsfiddle.net/rfhesoc6/